# Format Adjustment in C

Tags: c, number-formatting

Like for example, I want to have this output

```
Subtotal           20
Discount(10%)    -  2   //negative sign always have 2 spaces out from '2'
```

I tried to code like this.

```
dis = subtotal*discount/100; //dis = 20*10/100
printf("Subtotal%13d\n",subtotal);
printf("Discount(%d%s)%4s-%3d\n",discount,"%"," ",dis);
```

But what if it has no discount, my output will become like this

**Number are moved forward to left hand side**

```
Subtotal           20
Discount(0%)    -  0
```

Also, if my subtotal and discount are very large.

**Negative sign and number are sticking together**

```
Subtotal         1000
Discount(50%)    -500
```

How to code this until my number never move forward to left hand side or right hand side in between the discount (0%-100%) and always make 2 spaces between negative sign and the numbers (dis) ?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but why do you pass `"%"` as an argument? Why not print it directly? It can be escaped by a percentage character, so `"%%"` will print a single `%` character.

Comment: Do you mean why I don't do like this ("Discount(%d%)...") ?

Comment: Rather `"%d%%"`, but yes that's what I wonder. :)

Comment: Does this do what you need ? `printf("Discount(%3d%%)    -  %-d\n",discount,dis);` (seems he comment ate up some spaces - there are supposed to be 4 spaces before the `-`, and 2 spaces after)

Comment: @SanderDeDycker not really

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude oh sorry I didn't know about it since that I just a new learner in C haha

Comment: @SanderDeDycker the output will be like this if my discount is zero percent, `Discount(  0%)`

Comment: if you don't want that, then I'm afraid `printf` might not be suited for your needs - you're probably better off doing your own formatting. There's one other option left to you though : tabs : `printf("Discount(%d%%)\t- %-d\n",discount,dis);`, but I suspect that will also not be exactly what you need.

Comment: @SanderDeDycker sorry to say that, it is still not working, my discount number will still moved forward to left hand side when my discount is zero

Comment: I suspected as much - when using tabs, all depends on where the tab stops are

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it, using:

- the return of `printf` which tell you how characters have been printed
- the `log10` function which can be used to know the number of character in an integer:

The code could looks like:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* get number of character in a number (when printed)*/
int int_print_size(int number)
{
    if (number < 1) 
        return 1;

    else 
        return 1+log10(number);
}


void print(int subtotal, int discount)
{
    char spaces[] = "             ";

    int dis = subtotal*discount/100; //dis = 20*10/100
    int ref, len[2];

    /* take size of first line as reference */
    ref = printf("Subtotal%13d\n",subtotal);
    /* take the size of first part */
    len[0] = printf("Discount(%d%%)",discount);
    /* compute the printed size of `dis` */
    len[1] = int_print_size(dis);

    /* pad with characters from `spaces` array */
    printf("%.*s-  %d\n\n", ref-4-len[0]-len[1], spaces, dis);           

} 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){       
    /* tests case */
    print(20, 0);
    print(20, 10);
    print(100, 9);
    print(100, 10);
    print(100, 11);
    print(1000, 50);
    print(100000, 99);

    return 0;
}
```

With result:

```
Subtotal           20
Discount(0%)     -  0

Subtotal           20
Discount(10%)    -  2

Subtotal          100
Discount(9%)     -  9

Subtotal          100
Discount(10%)   -  10

Subtotal          100
Discount(11%)   -  11

Subtotal         1000
Discount(50%)  -  500

Subtotal       100000
Discount(99%)-  99000
```

Comment: Although this can't deal with `Discount(100%)` but still thanks !

Comment: `1+log10(number)` returned as `int` is prone to "off-by-one" problems and any time `number <= 0`.  E.g. `1+log10(1000)` may be 3.99999999999999...and the sum gets truncated to `3`.  Could use `len[1] = snprint(NULL, 0, "%d", dis);`

Comment: @chux You're right, but this is only valid in C99.... Yes my compiler is more than 20 years old...

Comment: @chux I got this error when I use this `implicit declaration of function 'snprintf' is invalid in C99` so what should I do in order to run this in just a function ?

Comment: @purplepsycho I don't really understand the part of `return 1+log10(number)`, if I want to do it in main function, what should I change from this ?

Comment: @Jeeremy `snprintf` should be declared via a  previous `#include <stdlib.h>` with C99.  Else try `char tmp[41]; len[1] = sprint(tmp, "%d", dis);`

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there is no flag to add spacing between the `-` and the number, but one solution might be to add an additional string buffer to write out the desired format:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char discount_amount_string[255];
    char discount_percent_string[255];
    int subtotal = 2000;
    int discount_percent = 10;
    int discount_amount = subtotal * discount_percent / 100;

    snprintf(discount_amount_string, sizeof(discount_amount_string), "-  %d", discount_amount);
    snprintf(discount_percent_string, sizeof(discount_percent_string), "(%d%%)", discount_percent);
    printf("Subtotal%15d\n",subtotal);
    printf("Discount%-7s%8s\n", discount_percent_string, discount_amount_string);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: it worked fine when the discount percent is in two digits `(20%)` but it is not working when it is in 1 or 3 digits `(0%) or (100%)`, number still moved to left hand side

Comment: Oh! Assumed that value would be constant. I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You were pretty close. The problem was that, if you just specify the width of the number, it is going to be *right justified* by default, which is why different sized numbers are going to be printed in different places.

Something like this ought to be closer to what you're looking for:

```
printf("Discount(%d%%)    -  %d\n",discount,dis);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, my number discount still moved forward to left hand side.

Comment: @TimRandall : the op wants all the `-` signs to be aligned vertically, even with different values of `discount`

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to have fixed number of spaces between the `-` and the first digit, just output the spaces: `"Discount(%2d%%)    -  %d\n"`

Note, however, that this will make it hard to align with the line above as the width of the number depends on its magnitude. To achieve alignment with the line above, you either need to go for a fixed field width for your discount number (and live the extra whitespace, and the failures when large numbers are at play), or you need to calculate the width of the second line first, and pad the first line accordingly. The later can be achieved by using `asprintf()` to write the second line into a newly allocated string, then take the length of that string, and format the first line accordingly. Last step would be to output the string for the second line verbatim.

Comment: Sorry to say that, could you do that for me by using the `asprintf()` if possible ?

Comment: @Jeeremy `asprintf()` is a function that's available on all modern linux systems, and it's well documented. A quick google reveals the man-page online: http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/asprintf.3.html You can find the same information with a simple `man asprintf`.

Comment: Btw.: Looking at that man-page, I see that `asprintf()` conveniently returns the number of printed characters, ready to be used to derive your padding width...

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with the `printf` family, you can do something like :

```
void print(int subtotal, int discount, int dis) {
    char buf[255] = { 0 };
    sprintf(buf, "Discount(%d%%)", discount);
    printf("%-21s   %4d\n", "Subtotal", subtotal);
    printf("%-21s-  %4d\n", buf, dis);
}
```

It unfortunately uses an intermediate buffer. If you want to avoid that, I suspect you're better off rolling your own formatting code for this specific case.